# PHP - Multi processing slower than single processing

Tags: php, process

I've got a PHP script doing calculation on a set of images. Typically, processing one set of image takes 30 seconds.

The parent process is forked once or more to do calculations on different sets of images at the same time. Only child processes perform calculations.

I have 8 cores on my Ubuntu machine, with an SSD drive

When I fork the parent process only once, so I've got the parent process and the child process, the child process completes the calculations on the image set in about 30 sec.

If I fork the parent process twice (so 1 parent and two child processes), each children takes about 100 seconds to complete its task.

If I fork the parent process four times (so 1 parent and four child processes), each children takes about 230 seconds to complete its task.

```
while (false !== ($nextTask = $this->selectNextTask())) 
{
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid == -1) 
        {
           //Fork failed
            continue;
        } 
        else if ($pid) {
            // In parent process
            $tasks[$pid] = $nextTask;
            $nextTask->initialize($pid);
            continue;
        } 
        else 
        {
         $nextTask->run(); //Actual Calculations
            exit(0); //end of child process
        }
}

//Parent process then waits for all child processes to complete
```

The actual processing loads images from the disk into ImageMagik objects and processes these images.

Am I missing something?

Comment: is there any dependencies between your forked process ? i mean **Process A** waiting for a ressource to be released by **Process 2** ??

Comment: No, they are completely independant

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick was the culprit. It looks like Image magick allocated 8 threads to each resource by default. The number of thread can be retrieved as below

```
$image->getresourcelimit(6);// 6 = nb threads
```

Consequently, there were far too many threads when using multi processing

I limited the number of threads as follows

```
$image->setresqourcelimit(6,2);// 2 threads
```

After that, multi processing worked as expected